# Cordova, missing html files when deploying from Visual Studio to device

Tags: angularjs, device, sample, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Cordova and building it using Visual Studio. I build my app on AngularJS example project http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-TODO-Sample-for-b651512a/.

I create *.html views for my directives like always in Angular apps. In emulator it's working fine but I get 404 when uploaded to physical tablet (Android).

What can cause it?

Comment: Could you clarify if you're modifying the existing sample app before running it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I bet we will probably help someone else :)
This is just one possibility of why your views would not be found on your device even though they really are there:
It seems that Android and iOS devices are case sensitive when you try and locate the paths.